# Conditionally trigger Jenkins multibranch pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a parameterized Jenkins multibranch pipeline using a GitHub repo as the source for a Jenkinsfile and some scripts. The pipeline is configured to trigger on webhooks for branches and pull requests but I also want a parameterized cron trigger only for the master branch, specifically every 4hours on weekdays.

I'm using declarative pipeline syntax but I'm willing to use scripted pipeline if necessary.

I'm using the [parameterized scheduler plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-scheduler-plugin) to achieve cron triggers with parameters.

This pipeline example captures what I am trying to achieve but is not supported:

```
pipeline {
  triggers {
    when { branch "master" }
    parameterizedCron('H */4 * * 1-5 % ABC=XYZ')
  }
  stages {
  // do something
  }
}
```

There is an open Jenkins issue for this feature: [JENKINS-42643](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42643) but it doesn't seem to be in development.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39168861/build-periodically-with-a-multi-branch-pipeline-in-jenkins/44902622#44902622

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using a ternary operator worked for my use case. Builds are only scheduled for the master branch:

```
pipeline {
  triggers {
    parameterizedCron(env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master' ? '''
# schedule every 4hours only on weekdays
H */4 * * 1-5 % ABC=XYZ''' : '')
  }
  parameters {
    string(name: 'ABC', defaultValue: 'DEF', description: 'test param')
  }
  stages {
    // do something
  }
}
```