# Jenkins trigger wrapper around pipeline shared library script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have shared global scripts available for our Jenkins repos.

They work by importing the shared library and executing it.

Many people may use the same shared library.

---

> Jenkinsfile (In my repo)

```
@Library('shared-stuff) _

runSharedTests()
```

---

> runSharedTests (In a completely separate repo)

```
def call() {
    def agent = getAgent()
    def setVariable = setAVariable()

    pipline {
        agent {
            label agent
        }
        stages {
            stage('Do Something') {
                steps {
                    executeSomething()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Is it possible to add a trigger to my Jenkinsfile that will trigger the `runSharedTests` pipeline periodically?

I cannot add the trigger directly to `runSharedTests` directly because then hundreds of repos will get that change and trigger.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What do you mean "affect anyone else"? How can you affect them?

Comment: @grolegor I reworded the question better

Comment: This is perfectly doable. See this question for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39168861/build-periodically-with-a-multi-branch-pipeline-in-jenkins

Answer (score 0):

In your case most suitable way to achieve your goal is making your jenkins job periodically. Your code does not need to be changed.

Configure → Build Triggers → Build periodically → Schedule:

> To allow periodically scheduled tasks to produce even load on the system, the symbol H (for “hash”) should be used wherever possible. For example, using `0 0 * * *` for a dozen daily jobs will cause a large spike at midnight. In contrast, using `H H * * *` would still execute each job once a day, but not all at the same time, better using limited resources.
>
> The H symbol can be used with a range. For example, `H H(0-7) * * *` means some time between 12:00 AM (midnight) to 7:59 AM. You can also use step intervals with `H`, with or without ranges.
>
> The `H` symbol can be thought of as a random value over a range, but it actually is a hash of the job name, not a random function, so that the value remains stable for any given project.
>
> Beware that for the day of month field, short cycles such as `*/3` or `H/3` will not work consistently near the end of most months, due to variable month lengths. For example, `*/3` will run on the 1st, 4th, …31st days of a long month, then again the next day of the next month. Hashes are always chosen in the 1-28 range, so `H/3` will produce a gap between runs of between 3 and 6 days at the end of a month. (Longer cycles will also have inconsistent lengths but the effect may be relatively less noticeable.)
>
> Empty lines and lines that start with `#` will be ignored as comments.
>
> In addition, `@yearly`, `@annually`, `@monthly`, `@weekly`, `@daily`, `@midnight`, and `@hourly` are supported as convenient aliases. These use the hash system for automatic balancing. For example, `@hourly` is the same as `H * * * *` and could mean at any time during the hour. `@midnight` actually means some time between 12:00 AM and 2:59 AM.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> # every fifteen minutes (perhaps at :07, :22, :37, :52)
> H/15 * * * *
> # every ten minutes in the first half of every hour (three times, perhaps at :04, :14, :24)
> H(0-29)/10 * * * *
> # once every two hours every weekday (perhaps at 10:38 AM, 12:38 PM, 2:38 PM, 4:38 PM)
> H 9-16/2 * * 1-5
> # once a day on the 1st and 15th of every month except December
> H H 1,15 1-11 *
> ```

Another way is using the [triggers](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers) directive. It defines the automated ways in which the Pipeline should be re-triggered. For example:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers {
        cron('H */4 * * 1-5')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But note that the declarative style is used here.

Comment: Can I use triggers if I'm importing a shared library function?

Comment: @ClickThisNick yes, you don't need to edit source code of the shared library. You can use shared library and declarative style which supports triggers at the same time. I don't see any restriction for this. Did you try that?